# How many strings of legth $L$ are there with the following restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I have a set of letters $S=\{ a_1, a_2,...a_k , a_{k+1} ,...a_n \}$

1. How many strings of length $L$ made of those letters are there, such that there are exactly $m_1$ $a_1$'s, $m_2$ $a_2$'s,...,$m_k$ $a_k$'s and $m_1+m_2+...+m_k \leq L$?
   And
2. answer the previous question with an extra restriction that all $a_i$ must always be together (next to each other).

Here's how I thought about it, I will count first all strings that start with $a_i$'s for example
$$a_1a_1...(m_1   times) a_2a_2...(m_2  times) ...a_ka_k (m_k  times) x_1 x_2...x_{L-(m_1+m_2+...+m_k)} $$
where $x_i$ are other letters from the alphabet given ($S$).

The number of such strings is

$$1 \cdot 1 \cdot ... \cdot 1 (m_1+...m_k  times) \cdot (n-k)(n-k)...(L-(m_1+...m_k ) times) $$

So if I consider all permutations, the possible strings are $$(n-k)^{L-m_1-m_2-...-m_k} L!$$

And for the second question I will identify all $a_i$ for each $i$ as a single letter, find all the possible permutations similar to the previous argument and divide by $m_i!$

So the number of strings are $$\frac{(n-k)^{L-k} L! }{m_1!m_2!...m_k!}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Not every permutation of your frontloaded starting string is going to give you a unique output. For example what about permutations that permute only the first $m_1$ characters, while leaving all the others alone. All of those permutations will leave the string unchanged. Even if you account for the demanded duplications, some of the remaining free picks can be duplicates to, so you also need to account for that. For the second problem, if you are still calculating $L!$ permutations, then you haven't treated all the $a_i$ as a single letter, have you?

Answer (score 1):

Look at (2) first. Suppose all the $m_i > 0$, and for sanity's sake, let $$M = L - \sum_{i=1}^k m_i.$$ As you've said, we can treat each of the $a_i$ blocks as being a single letter. That means we have $k$ demanded letters, and $M$ picks of the remaining letters $(n-k)$ letters, for $M + k$ picks total. Out of those $M+k$ picks, there are $\binom{M+k}{k}$ ways of placing the demanded letters, and $(n - k)^M$ ways of filling in the remaining $M$ letters.

For (1) you need to consider how many ways can you distribute the $m_1\ a_1$s among the $L$ positions. Then how many ways can you distribute the $m_2\ a_2$s among the remaining $L - m_1$ positions, etc. Finally, how many ways can the remaining $M$ positions be filled from the other letters?